# jquery hide show not work in radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to hide/show `div` with ID `#edate` when the selected radio input is "yes"/"no". Below is my code.

```
 <div id="edate">
    <label>End date</label>
    <input name="enddate" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="date">      
   </div>
   <div>
  <label>Continue</label>
  <input name="continue" id="continue" value="1" type="radio"> Yes </label>
  <input name="continue" id="nocontinue" value="0"  type="radio"> No </label>
 </div>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if (data.continue == 1) {
        $("#nocontinue").removeAttr('checked');
        $("#continue").attr('checked', 'checked'); 
        $("#edate").hide();
    } else {
        $("#continue").removeAttr('checked');
        $("#nocontinue").attr('checked', 'checked');
        $("#edate").show();
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: You're running your code when the document is ready, not when the user clicks.

Comment: What is `data.continue`?

Comment: You don't need to change the buttons' `checked` attribute, that happens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Do something, when an options is clicked like this:

```
$('#continue').on('click', function() {
    $("#edate").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

*HTML*

```
<div id="edate">
<label>End date</label>
<input name="enddate" id="enddate" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="date">      
</div>
<div>
<label>Continue</label>
<input name="continue" class="clContinue" id="continue" value="1" type="radio"> Yes 
<input name="continue" class="clContinue" id="nocontinue" value="0"  type="radio"> No 
</div>
```

*JQuery*

```
$(function(){
    $('.clContinue').click(function(){
        JSON.parse($(this).val())?$('#enddate').show():$('#enddate').hide();
    });
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/3tfak798/

Comment: The best approach, I think. Smart and simple.

Comment: Thanks @AdrienLeber .

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
  $("#continue").on('click',function(){
   $("#edate").hide();
  }); 
  $("#nocontinue").on('click',function(){
   $("#edate").show();
  }); 

        
 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edate">
    <label>End date</label>
    <input name="enddate" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="date">      
   </div>
   <div>
  <label>Continue</label>
  <input name="continue" id="continue" value="1" type="radio"> Yes </label>
  <input name="continue" id="nocontinue" value="0"  type="radio"> No </label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is easy to find on SO.

Here is some codes I found with 2 min search on the forum :

**HTML**

```
 <div id="edate">
    <label>End date</label>
    <input name="enddate" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="date">      
   </div>
   <div>
  <label>Continue</label>
  <input name="continue" id="continue" value="1" type="radio"> Yes </label>
  <input name="continue" id="nocontinue" value="0"  type="radio"> No </label>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  switch(this.value){
    case '1':
      $("#edate").show();
      break;
    case '0':
      $("#edate").hide();
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#continue,#nocontinue').on('click',function(){
  $(this).val() == '1' ? $("#edate").show() : $("#edate").hide();  
})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ftjpdvrz/

Answer (score 0):

Use a common event for radio group. Also, if default is "Yes", make it as Checked in HTML.

```
$(function(){

$('input[name=continue]').on('click',function(){      
  if($(this).val() == "1"){
      $('#edate').show();
    }else{
    $('#edate').hide();
    }

});

});
```